# Coremltools: errors to get simplest convolutional model working

Tags: keras, coreml, coremltools

Suppose I create simplest model in Keras:

```
from keras.layers import *
from keras import Input, Model

import coremltools


def MyModel(inputs_shape=(None,None,3), channels=64):

        inpt = Input(shape=inputs_shape)

        # channels
        skip = Conv2D(channels, (3, 3), strides=1, activation=None, padding='same', name='conv_in')(inpt)
        out = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), strides=1, padding='same', activation='tanh',name='out')(skip)

        return Model(inputs=inpt, outputs=out)


model = MyModel()


coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model,
    input_names=["inp1"],
    output_names=["out1"],
    image_scale=1.0,
    model_precision='float32',
    use_float_arraytype=True,
    input_name_shape_dict={'inp1': [None, 384, 384, 3]}
    )


spec = coreml_model._spec


print(spec.description.input[0])

print(spec.description.input[0].type.multiArrayType.shape)

print(spec.description.output[0])


coremltools.utils.save_spec(spec, "test.mlmodel")
```

The output is:

```
2 : out, <keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7f08ca491470>
3 : out__activation__, <keras.layers.core.Activation object at 0x7f08ca4b0b70>
name: "inp1"
type {
  multiArrayType {
    shape: 3
    shape: 384
    shape: 384
    dataType: FLOAT32
  }
}

[3, 384, 384]
name: "out1"
type {
  multiArrayType {
    shape: 3
    dataType: FLOAT32
  }
}
```

So the output shape is 3, which is incorrect. And when I try to get rid from `input_name_shape_dict` I get:

```
Please provide a finite height (H), width (W) & channel value (C) using input_name_shape_dict arg with key = 'inp1' and value = [None, H, W, C]
Converted .mlmodel can be modified to have flexible input shape using coremltools.models.neural_network.flexible_shape_utils
```

So it wants NHWC.

Attempt of inference yields:

`Layer 'conv_in' of type 'Convolution' has input rank 3 but expects rank at least 4`

When I attempt to add extra dimension to input:

```
spec.description.input[0].type.multiArrayType.shape.extend([1, 3, 384, 384])
del spec.description.input[0].type.multiArrayType.shape[0]
del spec.description.input[0].type.multiArrayType.shape[0]
del spec.description.input[0].type.multiArrayType.shape[0]
```

```
[name: "inp1"
type {
  multiArrayType {
    shape: 1
    shape: 3
    shape: 384
    shape: 384
    dataType: FLOAT32
  }
}
]
```

I get for inference:

`Shape (1 x 384 x 384 x 3) was not in enumerated set of allowed shapes`

Following [this advice](https://github.com/apple/coremltools/issues/672) and making input shape `(1,1,384,384,3)` dos not help.

How can I make it working and producing correct output?

Inference:

```
From PIL import Image

model_cml = coremltools.models.MLModel('my.mlmodel')

# load image
img = np.array(Image.open('patch4.png').convert('RGB'))[np.newaxis,...]/127.5 - 1

# Make predictions
predictions = model_cml.predict({'inp1':img})

# save result
res = predictions['out1']
res = np.clip((res[0]+1)*127.5,0,255).astype(np.uint8)

Image.fromarray(res).save('out32.png')
```

UPDATE:

I am able to run this model with inputs `(3,1,384,384)`, the result produces is `(1,3,3,384,384)` which does not make any sense for me.

UPDATE 2:

setting fixed shape in Keras

```
def MyModel(inputs_shape=(384,384,3), channels=64):

        inpt = Input(shape=inputs_shape)
```

fixed output shape problem, but I still cannot run the model (`Layer 'conv_in' of type 'Convolution' has input rank 3 but expects rank at least 4`)

UPDATE:

The following works to get rid of input and conv_in shapes mismatch.

1). Downgrade to `coremltools==3.0`. Version 3.3 (model version 4) seems broken.

2.) Use fixed shape in keras model, no input_shape_dist and variable shape for coreml model

```
from keras.layers import *
from keras import Input, Model

import coremltools


def MyModel(inputs_shape=(384,384,3), channels=64):

        inpt = Input(shape=inputs_shape)

        # channels
        skip = Conv2D(channels, (3, 3), strides=1, activation=None, padding='same', name='conv_in')(inpt)
        out = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), strides=1, padding='same', activation='tanh',name='out')(skip)

        return Model(inputs=inpt, outputs=out)


model = MyModel()

model.save('test.model')

print(model.summary())

'''
# v.3.3
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model,
    input_names=["image"],
    output_names="out1",
    image_scale=1.0,
    model_precision='float32',
    use_float_arraytype=True,
    input_name_shape_dict={'inp1': [None, 384, 384, 3]}
    )
'''

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert(model,
    input_names=["image"],
    output_names="out1",
    image_scale=1.0,
    model_precision='float32',

    )


spec = coreml_model._spec


from coremltools.models.neural_network import flexible_shape_utils
shape_range = flexible_shape_utils.NeuralNetworkMultiArrayShapeRange()
shape_range.add_channel_range((3,3))
shape_range.add_height_range((64, 384))
shape_range.add_width_range((64, 384))
flexible_shape_utils.update_multiarray_shape_range(spec, feature_name='image', shape_range=shape_range)


print(spec.description.input)

print(spec.description.input[0].type.multiArrayType.shape)

print(spec.description.output)


coremltools.utils.save_spec(spec, "my.mlmodel")
```

In the inference script, feed array of the shape `(1,1,3,384,384)`:

```
img = np.zeros((1,1,3,384,384))

# Make predictions
predictions = model_cml.predict({'inp1':img})
res = predictions['out1'] # (3, 384,384)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore what the mlmodel file has in the output shape if it is incorrect. This is more of a metadata issue, i.e. the model will still work fine and do the right thing. The converter isn't always able to figure out the correct output shape (not sure why).

Comment: I also found that coremltools==3.3 seems to be broken. I got rid of convolutional layer shape issue by 1) swithching to version 3.0 2) not providing `input_name_shape_dict` 3) Using fixed input size in keras model 4) Using channel-first data ordering and feeding `(1,1,3,384,384)` as input... That allowed me to at least infer this simple model without errors

Comment: Oh, and I forgot - it will still issue error `shape (3,384,384)" is not in the list of allowed shapes`, so you need to add shape variablilty ```from coremltools.models.neural_network import flexible_shape_utils
shape_range = flexible_shape_utils.NeuralNetworkMultiArrayShapeRange()
shape_range.add_channel_range((3,3))
shape_range.add_height_range((64, 384))
shape_range.add_width_range((64, 384))
flexible_shape_utils.update_multiarray_shape_range(spec, feature_name='image', shape_range=shape_range)```